# Question about weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

So here is my question,

In a exercise I have to decide if the following holds,

Let $X$ be a normed vectorspace and let $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ i.e $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges weak to $x$. And let $f_n\rightarrow f$ for $f_n,f\in X^*$.

Then,
$$f_n(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$$

I am not sure if this is true but I think the statement is wrong since everytime I assumed it is correct and started to prove it, I arrived somewhere, where strong convergence of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ was required to show that the statement holds... So I even think that this implies strong convergence of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$.

Could someone help me and tell me if I am correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a weakly convergent sequence is bounded, so there is a $C < \infty$ with $\lVert x_n\rVert \leqslant C$ for all $n$. Further,

$$f_n(x_n) - f(x) = \bigl(f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)\bigr) + \bigl( f(x_n) - f(x)\bigr).$$

The weak convergence $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ and the norm convergence $f_n \to f$ together are sufficient to conclude $f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks, I see that I can use $f_n(x_n)-f(x)=...$ to aplly the triangular inequality. Then the first term diasappears since we have strog convergence of $f_n$ and only $|f(x_n)-f(x)|=|f(x_n-x)|\leq||f|||x_n-x|$...  stays. But I somehow dont see where to use the bound $C$?

Comment: You use $\lVert x_n\rVert \leqslant C$ to show the first term converges to $0$. For the second, $\lvert f(x_n) - f(x)\rvert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert\cdot \lVert x_n-x\rVert$ is the wrong thing, that won't get you to the target. What does $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ mean?

Comment: AH I see! the second term becomes $0$ because of waek convergence :D sorry that was stupid from my side! Thank you very much for the help!!